# OpenGL glScale and glLoadMatrix

Tags: opengl, matrix, transformation

I'm writing an 3D Scanner with a Kinect and i want to display the Point clouds..

The Pointclouds have an additional Transformmatrix from a Trackingsystem..

I use:
scale = 0.0005;
glScaled(scale, scale, scale);

to encounter the Problem, that x,y,z Value ranges from 0 - 10.000 are cut by Opengl due to clipping planes.

when i use glLoadMatrix(trackingtransform); i don't see anything.. even if i use glscale again after the loadmatrix.

Comment: You're very vague, at best. OpenGL has no hard limits, where it clips. I simply suspect you're not setting up projection and modelview properly. Please show some code. Most notably where you setup modelview and projection matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glLoadMatrix replaces the matrix that you generated with glScaled.

if you want to combine them, use glMultMatrix instead of glLoadMatrix.

That said, I'd advise to do what datenwolf alludes to. Use the projection matrix to set a coordinate system that maps your usage scenario (i.e. a world in the 0-10000 range), and keep the modelview matrix to move around.

Comment: *facepalm* i'm new to opengl. setting up a projectionmatrix would've saved me some hours.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can directly scale the matrix your points are in, like:

```
glPushMatrix();
glScale();
-draw all your points...
glPopMatrix();
```